server returned HTTP status 404 Not Found in prometheus
i am using this config file for prometheus, i am trying to expose the metrics of  'dev' environment to the prometheus app which is in prometheus namespace . All the below files are defined in prometheus namespace .
 apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server-conf
  namespace: prometheus
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 15s
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'dev-pods'
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        action: keep
        regex: dev  # Keep only the dev namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: container  # Specify the target label for the container name
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: pod  # Specify the target label for the pod name
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_(.+)  # Copy all Kubernetes pod labels

and this is my service file for prometheus
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  name: prometheus-service
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9090  # Fixed indentation
  type: LoadBalancer

and this is my deployment file for prometheus
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
           mountPath: /etc/prometheus
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-server-conf  # Correctly referencing the ConfigMap
            defaultMode: 420

for some pods i am getting this error Get "http://10.1.58.5:8080/metrics": dial tcp 10.1.58.5:8080: connect: connection refused
, can someone tell me why am i getting this error server returned HTTP status 404 Not Found in the targets of prometheus dashboard .
http://10.1.55.167:5005/metrics while clicking on the endpoint , i am getting 404 page not found
